# Display the column when inline edit is used & hide the same column in display mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Kendoui grid, in this i need to hide the field when it is in display mode,

But when i click on edit button it should show the column.

Example:-

In disaplymode it shows 6 column,

and in edit mode shows 7 columns.

Please send me related sample code.

Thanks in Advance.